# Why the issue of "Change in orientation of image" that is captured using device camera and uploaded to FTP server persists in following scenario?

Tags: php, ftp, orientation, image-uploading, exif

I'm using **PHP 5.5.19** for my website.

I'm allowing users to take photograph by using their smart device camera and uploading the same image to the FTP server using PHP.

**The issue I'm facing is with change in image orientation.**

Suppose, if user takes a photograph in 'Portrait' orientation of his device and uploads the same photograph to the FTP server, the orientation of uploaded photograph should be 'Portrait' only but in my case it's changing to 'Landscape' and vice-versa.

To fix this issue I wrote following code but it didn't work out for me. So after trying everything I'm asking for your help.

**HTML code:**

```
<form id="request_form" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
  <input type="file" name="student_image" id="student_image" accept="image/*" capture/>
</form>
```

**PHP Code:**

```
if(!empty($_FILES['student_image']['name'])) {

  $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['student_image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);     

  $student_image_name = 'student_'.'.'.$ext;
  $_POST['student_name'] = $student_image_name;

  $ftp_server="52.237.5.85"; 
  $ftp_user_name="myservercreds"; 
  $ftp_user_pass="MyServerCreds";


  $file = $_FILES['student_image']['name'];//tobe uploaded 
  $remote_file = "/Students/".$_POST['student_name'];        


  // set up basic connection 
  $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);  

  // login with username and password 
  $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

  // turn passive mode on
  ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

  if($login_result) {
    if(!is_dir('ftp://myservercreds:MyServerCreds@52.237.5.85/Students')) {
      ftp_mkdir($conn_id, "/Students");
      ftp_chmod($conn_id, 0777, '/Students');
    }

    if(!file_exists("/Students/".$student_image_name))
      $file_upload_status = ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_BINARY);

    //Below is the code I've written to overcome this issue but unfortunately same thing is happening again          
    if($file_upload_status) {
      $exif = exif_read_data($remote_file);
      $ort = $exif['COMPUTED']['Orientation'];
      switch($ort) {

        case 3: // 180 rotate left
          $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($remote_file); 
          $rotated = imagerotate($image, 180, -1);
          break;

        case 6: // 90 rotate right
          $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($remote_file); 
          $rotated = imagerotate($image, -90, -1);
          break;

        case 8:    // 90 rotate left
          $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($remote_file); 
          $rotated = imagerotate($image, 90, -1);
          break;
      }

      imagejpeg($rotated, $remote_file);
      $success_message = 'Photo Successfully Uploaded';
    }
  }        
  // close the connection 
  ftp_close($conn_id);
}
```

If you need any further information regarding the issue I'm facing please do let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that  you need to ftp_put after it is rotated, -save localy - rotate then ftp put.

Comment: But what's the issue in accessing the image from remote server and overwriting it after rotating?

Comment: @PHPLover Your $remote file is just string with path, that is not even pointing to your picture outside context of connection. your code will try to save it localy at same path (and most ikely fail due to chmod)

Comment: I tried your trick of storing the image locally first and then to FTP server. Still same is the result.